# Web Bluetooth API: Origin is not allowed to access the service

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

I am using web Bluetooth API, to connect a BLE device. Its working perfect on https://localhost. But when I try it on my live server which is also on https or when I try it on http://locahost, it throughs me this error " Origin is not allowed to access the service. Tip: Add the service UUID to 'optionalServices' in requestDevice() options.". The code is given below. I have already added optionalServices.

```
      scanDevices () {
            if(navigator.bluetooth) {
                navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
                    acceptAllDevices: true,
                    optionalService: ['0000fee0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb', '0000fee1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb']
                })
                .then(device => {
                    // save the device returned so you can disconnect later:
                    this.device = device;
                    this.device.addEventListener('gattserverdisconnected', this.onDisconnected);
                    // connect to the device once you find it:
                    return this.connect();
                })
                .then((server) => {
                    this.server = server;
                    return server;
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    // catch any errors:
                    console.error('Connection failed!', error);
                });
            } else {
                this.errorMessage = 'Your browser does not support web bluetooth API.';
            }

        },
        connect(){
            let connection = this.device.gatt.connect();
            console.log('Connected', connection);
            return connection;
        },
        readData (){
            this.isLoader = true;
            console.log('get the primary service:');
            console.log(this.server);
            this.server.getPrimaryService(this.parsedService)
            .then((service) => {
                console.log('get the  characteristic:');
                return service.getCharacteristic(this.parsedCharacteristic);
            })
            .then(characteristic => {
                return characteristic.readValue();
            })
            .then(value => {
                console.log(value);
                this.isLoader = false;
                let decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
                console.log(decoder.decode(value));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.isLoader = false;
                this.errorMessage = error.message;
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems like it is missing an "s" to `optionalService`. It should be `optionalServices` according to https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-requestdeviceoptions-optionalservices

Answer (score 0):

Download nRF app from playstore and connect to the BLE device and after connection you can get all the Primary Services and its UUID. Get the Primary Service UUID and place it on the `optionalServices[0xFEE0]` and get Primary Services Characterstics (listed inside primary services ) and place on 
`service.getCharacteristic(0x2A2B)`.

These codes are of MI BAND to get time and date.